# Updating NaN values in a dataframe when there's a match to a list item in another dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

beginner in Python here.
Have tried to look for a solution for this from a bunch of sites. 
Might just not be connecting the dots right.

I'm trying to fill the 'NaN' values in a DataFrame based on values present in a list.
If the persons name appears on the list, the 'geo' column should updated with the correct geo name. 
The lists are complete, with people in the regions, but the DataFrame is not and needs to be updated.

What I have looks roughly like this:

```
   name  geo 
0  john  EMEA
1  jack  NaN
2  jill  APAC
3  james NaN 
4  judy  EMEA
5  jared NaN
```

I would like to update the NaN values based on the below lists.

```
EMEA = ['john','jack','judy','jared']
APAC = ['jill','james']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for x in df.index:
    if df.loc[x,"name"] in EMEA:
        df.loc[x,"geo"]='EMEA'
    if df.loc[x,"name"] in APAC:
        df.loc[x,"geo"]="APAC"
```

Hope this helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

First create dictionaryby each list:

```
EMEA = ['john','jack','judy','jared']
APAC = ['jill','james']

d = {'EMEA' : EMEA,
     'APAC': APAC}
```

Then swap order with flatten:

```
d1 = {x: k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
print (d1)
{'john': 'EMEA', 'jack': 'EMEA', 'judy': 'EMEA',
 'jared': 'EMEA', 'jill': 'APAC', 'james': 'APAC'}
```

Last replace only misisng values by mapped values by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['geo'] = df['geo'].fillna(df['name'].map(d1))
print (df)
    name   geo
0   john  EMEA
1   jack  EMEA
2   jill  APAC
3  james  APAC
4   judy  EMEA
5  jared  EMEA
```

Or map all values:

```
df['geo'] = df['name'].map(d1)
print (df)
    name   geo
0   john  EMEA
1   jack  EMEA
2   jill  APAC
3  james  APAC
4   judy  EMEA
5  jared  EMEA
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple np.where should resolve this:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

```
df['geo'] = np.where((df['geo'].isnull()) & (df['name'].isin(MEA)), 'MEA',
            np.where((df['geo'].isnull()) & (df['name'].isin(APAC)), 'APAC',
                      pdf['geo']))
```